# How to simplify multiple COUNTIFS in excel with non-consecutive ranges

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I have a spreadsheet...

[image: Excel SpreadSheet]

A you can see, the cell F2 has a formula with multiple COUNTSIF, basicly checks the cells F14, F33, F62 y there is a Pass there, and if there is one will give you a % completion. My question is that I have to add around 20-30 COUNTIFS to that formula, is there a way to simplify it.

`=(COUNTIF(F14,"Pass")+COUNTIF(F33,"Pass")+COUNTIF(F62,"Pass")+COUNTIF(F75,"Pass")+COUNTIF(F88,"Pass")+COUNTIF(F105,"Pass"))/(COUNTIFS(F14,"<>na")+COUNTIFS(F33,"<>na")+COUNTIFS(F62,"<>na")++COUNTIFS(F75,"<>na")++COUNTIFS(F88,"<>na")+COUNTIFS(F105,"<>na"))`

This is not the final formula, still missing around 20 entries. If you're wondering why not do a simple F15:FXX, because i just need the cells that have a test case name, like F14, F33, etc.

Comment: Is there any unambiguous indication how rows with the name of the test case can be distinguished from other rows. For example, is the 'Test case' column filled only for these entries? Does the 'Reference' column always start with a number for these entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your formula, you can use the `INDEX` function to return a non-contiguous set of values, which you can test.

For example, the equivalent for the first part would be:

```
=SUM(N(INDEX($F:$F,IF(1,N({14,33,62,75,88,105})))="Pass"))
```

The `IF(1,N({…}))` part is how you specify which cells (rows) in Column `F` to return.

Without knowing more about your data, not sure about handling the percentage issue.

*Your posted formula would not calculate a percentage, as it is only dividing the `SUM` by whether or not `F14<>"na"` is true, and then adding one for the `<>"na"` factor for the rest*

In earlier versions of Excel, you may need to confirm this **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

If you want to return the percent "pass" in your list of cells, merely divide the `SUM` by the number of cells.  You can either hard-code that number, or compute it with something like:

```
 COLUMNS({14,33,62,75,88,105})
```

Or all together:

```
=SUM(N(INDEX($F:$F,IF(1,N({14,33,62,75,88,105})))="Pass"))/6
```

or

```
=SUM(N(INDEX($F:$F,IF(1,N({14,33,62,75,88,105})))="Pass"))/COLUMNS({14,33,62,75,88,105})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I'll explain more in detail. And hopefully you can help me out with this. What I'm trying to do is on CELL F2 have a formula that checks all PASS verdicts from Column F, but only certain cells (there are not in consecutive order) and give a % of completion. If all of them have a pass then it's 100 % completed. Right now it works but i have to add all those ranges to my formula. And makes it extremely long.

Comment: @AndresMartinez Just divide the SUM function I provided by the number of cells being checked.